# Corrupted files downloaded from Amazon S3 using AFAmazonS3Client

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, plist, afnetworking-2

I created an app that download a plist file from Amazon S3.  I was using [AFAmazonS3Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client) a client based in [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) framework.

```
-(void) getFile:(NSString *)fileName{
    self.s3Manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:@"..." secret:@"..."];
    self.s3Manager.requestSerializer.region = AFAmazonS3SAEast1Region;
    self.s3Manager.requestSerializer.bucket = @"verba";

    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    documentsPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:documentsPath append:NO];

    [self.s3Manager getObjectWithPath:@""
                         outputStream:stream
                             progress:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
         NSLog(@"%f%% Downloaded", (totalBytesRead / (totalBytesExpectedToRead * 1.0f) * 100));
    } success:^(id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"Download Complete");
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Then I checked if the plist file was in document folder. And it was. So I tried to open plist file and the result was nil:

```
-(NSString*) loadListName:(NSString*)fileName{
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSDictionary *temp;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: filePath]){
        temp = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File not found.");
    }

    NSString *listName = [temp objectForKey:@"name"];

    return listName;
}
```

So I tried to add plist file manually. I downloaded and copied it to the documents folder and then `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` could open the file. So I suppose that plist file was corrupted when I download the file using [AFAmazonS3Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client).

What I am doing wrong ?

**Update 1**

I realize that every single file that I downloaded from S3 are corrupted. I don't know if I handle the NSOutputStream in the right way or maybe another stuff.

Comment: For debugging read the file as a `NSString` and `NSSLog` it. If the problem is not apparent try verifying the plist with an app. Or add the strip contents to your question if it is not to long or confidential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason `getObjectWithPath` method from `AFAmazonS3Manager` is not working properly.

So I rewrite my method using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` directly from [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

```
- (void)downloadFile:(NSString *)fileName block:(void (^)(NSError *error))block {

    NSString *urlString = @"https://[bucket].[server area].amazonaws.com/";
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    NSSet *set = operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes;

    if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"m4a"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ set as audio/mp4", fileName);
        operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [set setByAddingObject:@"audio/mp4"];
    } else if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ set as image/png", fileName);
        operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [set setByAddingObject:@"image/png"];
    } else if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"plist"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ set as application/x-plist", fileName);
        operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [set setByAddingObject:@"application/x-plist"];
    }

    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];

    [operation setOutputStream:[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:fullPath append:NO]];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        NSLog(@"bytesRead: %lu, totalBytesRead: %lld, totalBytesExpectedToRead: %lld", (unsigned long)bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
    }];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (block) {
            block(nil);
        }

        NSLog(@"RES: %@", [[[operation response] allHeaderFields] description]);

        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERR: %@", [error description]);
        } else {
            NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
            long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];

            NSLog(@"%lld", fileSize);
        }


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (block) {
            block(error);
        }
        NSLog(@"ERR: %@", [error description]);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be carefull cause in last versión of Xcode, every time you restart your app in simulator, the documents folder is deleted